# Power series ring $R[[X_1,\ldots,X_d]]$ over a domain $R$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, deformation-theory, galois-representations, local-rings

Let $R$ be a domain and 
\begin{align*}
T \,\colon= R[[X_1,\ldots,X_d]].
\end{align*}
Suppose that we have $d$ elements $f_1,\ldots,f_d \in T$ and let us consider an ideal $J$ of $T$ such that $(f_1,\ldots,f_d) \subset J$ and the following three conditions$\colon$
\begin{align*}
&
1. \quad \overline{f_i} \,\colon \overset{{\mathrm{def}}}{=} f_i~{\mathrm{mod}}(X_1,\ldots,X_d)~{\mathrm{is~ an~ irreducible~ element~ of~}} R ~{\mathrm{for~each}}~ 1 \leq i \leq d. \\
&
2. \quad T/(f_1,\ldots,f_d) \phantom{a} {\mathrm{is}}~not~{\mathrm{finite~over}}~ R. \\
&
3. \quad T/J \phantom{a} {\mathrm{is~finite~over}}~R.  
\end{align*}

### Q. Does the following equality hold$\colon$$\phantom{A}$${\mathrm{ht}}(J) > d$$\,$?